# Does kryo serialization work on non serializable class and class have non serializable attributes?

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I'm trying to use Kryo library to convert any given object to byteArray and store in a data store or queue for later use. But is it possible to serialize any given object or only object implementing serializable interface can be converted.

Comment: It should be possible to serialize a bean also if it doesn't implement java.io.Serialiable, see for example the test class BeanSerializerTest.

Comment: @John-Donn Please make that an answer and provide a link the the example specified.

Comment: @MikePone added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to serialize/deserialize a bean with Kryo also if it doesn't implement java.io.Serialiable and/or if its attributes don't implement Serializable (I run the example with Kryo 2.10; there is the limitation that no argument constructors had to be explicitly defined here because non default constructors were present):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;

public class KryoSerializerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KryoHelper kryoHelper = new KryoHelper();
        ClassNotImplementingSerializable obj1 = new ClassNotImplementingSerializable(123, 456, "789");
        ClassNotImplementingSerializable obj2 = (ClassNotImplementingSerializable) kryoHelper.fromBytes(kryoHelper.toBytes(obj1));
        if (obj1.equals(obj2)) {
            System.out.println("the object and its clone are equal as expected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("the object and its clone are not equal, something went wrong");
        }
    }

    public static class KryoHelper {

        Kryo kryo;

        public KryoHelper() {
            super();
            kryo=new Kryo();
        }

        public byte[] toBytes(Object obj){
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try (Output output = new Output(baos)) {
                kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, obj);
            }

            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            return bytes;
        }

        public Object fromBytes(byte[] bytes){
            Object retrievedObject;
            try (Input input = new Input( new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))){
                retrievedObject = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
            }

            return retrievedObject;
        }

    }

    public static class ClassNotImplementingSerializable {
        private int a;
        private ClassNotImplementingSerializable2 b;

        /**
         * no-arg constructor is necessary
         */
        public ClassNotImplementingSerializable() {
        }
        public ClassNotImplementingSerializable(int a, int b, String c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = new ClassNotImplementingSerializable2(b,c);
        }
        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public ClassNotImplementingSerializable2 getB() {
            return b;
        }
        public void setB(ClassNotImplementingSerializable2 b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + a;
            result = prime * result + ((b == null) ? 0 : b.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ClassNotImplementingSerializable other = (ClassNotImplementingSerializable) obj;
            if (a != other.a)
                return false;
            if (b == null) {
                if (other.b != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!b.equals(other.b))
                return false;
            return true;
        }



    }

    public static class ClassNotImplementingSerializable2 {
        private int a;
        private String b;

        /**
         * no-arg constructor is necessary
         */
        public ClassNotImplementingSerializable2() {
        }
        public ClassNotImplementingSerializable2(int a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public String getB() {
            return b;
        }
        public void setB(String b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + a;
            result = prime * result + ((b == null) ? 0 : b.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ClassNotImplementingSerializable2 other = (ClassNotImplementingSerializable2) obj;
            if (a != other.a)
                return false;
            if (b == null) {
                if (other.b != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!b.equals(other.b))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

There can be problems with some specific field types, such as `java.sql.Timestamp` for example (there is a way around this one though), and of course `java.lang.Thread` and the likes.